# LBG function in Matlab - need code explanation

Tags: matlab

So this is the link for function: http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/kmeanlbg.html

I'm completely unfamiliar with Matlab and this line of code confuses me:

```
[x,esq,j]=v_kmeans(d,m,[x(1:n,:)+e(ones(n,1),:); x(1:n,:)-e(ones(n,1),:); x(n+1:m-n,:)]);
```

I guess it's calling the kmeans function, passing d-data and m-number of centers, but what does the next part of code mean? Is it calculation of coordinates of newly split centres? Can someone explain the syntax to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the next part is the initial centroids for the v_kmeans function.
It is acutally a matrix with the same number of columns as m.

Please take a look at the original document for this function.
http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/v_kmeans.html

Answer (score 0):

In laymans terms, preceding to that line of code, they're doing kmeans once, and then running a loop to do kmeans over and over again to get optimal cluster centers.

They do kmeans for vector quantization because they want to train (generate) the codebook by the use of the lbg (kmeans) algorithm.

They've then applied their own logic to it, so its up to you to either:-

a) figure it out

b) write your own code
Hope that helps.